# What happens during the night of Brahma?

Tags: brahma, kalpa

During Brahma's day , [living beings exist while during his night ,](https://www.quora.com/What-is-Kalpa-Manvantara-and-Yuga-in-Hindu-mythology/answer/Sumit-Shrivastava-6) living beings dies. Both day and night are 12 hours long.

So, for the whole 12 hours of Brahma , Pralay keeps on happening ? That is quite long time.

What exactly happens during his night ? What are the details about it ?

Comment: Your question does not make logical sense. You are asking - when there is no causation what is being caused? Or - When nothing is happening, what is happening?

Comment: At the onset of Brahmas day, entire creation manifests from the unmanifest.At the onset of Brahmas night, it is again dissolved into the  unmanifest.(Bhagava Gita 8.18)

Comment: Movie projector moves the film reel , and manifests the film on the screen.Movie does not perish once the show is over. It is unmanifest on the film reel . It again manifests on the next show. Although this is  not picture perfect analogy, It conveys the idea ,Nothing ever completely perishes on pralaya, it only becomes latent (Contemporary Analogy  courtesy - https://gitajourney.com)

Answer (score 1):

The Mahabharata Translated by Vivek Debroy, Vana Parva  chapter 194

> When the world became one terrible ocean and all mobile and immobile objects and all beings had been destroyed, the illustrious **Vishnu, the eternal and undecaying being, the source of everything in the world, slept alone on the ocean. He was stretched out on the great serpent Shesha, whose energy is limitless.** O illustrious one! The immensely fortunate Hari, the undecaying one and the creator of the world, slept in the coils of that great serpent, which encircled the expanse of the earth.

During the night of brahmA, Bhagavan Vishnu goes to sleep. Nothing else happens.

Answer (score 0):

**Shiva Purana 2.1:1:10.:**

> *चतुर्युगसहस्राणि ब्रह्मणो दिनमुच्यते ।
> रात्रिश्च तावती तस्य मानमेतत्क्रमेण ह ॥ १६ ॥*
>
> *16. A thousand sets of the four-yuga periods constitute one day of Brahmā. **The period of night is also similar.** Further measurement of time is based on this calculation.*

[image]

So, Lord Brahma's Day is one Kalpa and night is another kalpa. So, I guess, the dawn snd dusk are the temporary Pralaya period.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..